# Unexpected Error while using the predict() function in R for time series Data

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, predict

The data has half hourly load data (electricity demand) from 7/21/2009 11:30 to 7/23/2014 23:30. The variable "LOAD.MW" is measured sequentially in time at a fixed interval of time, so the resulting data may be considered to be a time series.

I have converted the data into "ts" class

```
data.ts <- ts(data$LOAD.MW, start=c(as.numeric(as.Date("2009/07/21")),26), 
              end=c(as.numeric(as.Date("2014/7/23")),48),frequency=48)
```

Then I have fitted the arima model:

```
 data.fit1 <- arima(data.ts, order = c(2,0,0))
 data.fit1

# Call:
# arima(x = data.ts, order = c(2, 0, 0))

# Coefficients:
#          ar1      ar2  intercept
#       1.8421  -0.8765  2675.7445
# s.e.  0.0016   0.0016     5.5789

# sigma^2 estimated as 3222:  log likelihood = -479024.8,  aic = 958057.7
```

Now I want to do some prediction. So, I have used the `predict` function:

```
data.pred1 <- predict(data.fit1,n.ahead=100)   #Making 100 half hour prediction
```

> Error in predict(data.fit1, n.ahead = 100) : 
>   unused argument (n.ahead = 100)

It is giving me an error. I am not able to understand why I am getting this error. Why the argument `n.ahead=100` is said unused? I used this function before also but then I worked for me. In fact I have also experienced that sometimes it works and sometime it does not.

Also when I tried to forecast using the `forecast()` function I got the same error.

```
forecast(data.fit1,5)
```

> Error in predict(object, n.ahead = h) : unused argument (n.ahead = h)

Please give ur expert opinion and help me to correct this error.

Comment: Please provide the output of `sessionInfo()` in your original post.

Comment: I suspect you have redefined the predict() function.